# Adb devices sees my phone, Android Studio doesn't

Tags: android, android-studio, usb, adb, device

I've recently changed the computer to MacBook Pro. In the Android Studio when I want to install the application (Select Deployment Target), I don't have any devices listed.
Strange things are that when I type `ADB devices` to the terminal I have my device listed there (not offline, its properly attached.). After building .apk and again typing in terminal `ADB install ...` i was able to install my application. What should I do to make Android Studio sees my device properly? I've tried restarting everything, I've turned off and on all the `programmer and debugging options` inside the phone. Also it's not showing any Virtual Devices I've created.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar behaviour on a Windows machine:
`adb devices` was listing the devices while Android Studio was not able to see it.
I've found out that the reason was that Android Studio was not able to find adb executable. I've fixed it on my machine by adding `[Path-to-android-sdk]\platform-tools\` folder to the PATH variable and restarting Android Studio.